# Networking issue in subdomain for two ISP - if one fails and other up

Tags: ubuntu, networking

We have a subdomain which is connected through a ISP-A in CNAME. Through subdomain, a Program runs in a local server with ISP A. If the ISP-A is down, then program doesn't run. So we have added ISP-B through router to local server. If ISP-A is down, Local server will pickup ISP-B. Now the real problem is, We have multiple work places. Both ISP runs perfectly at local station. If ISP-A is up and which is connected to C-Name, then issues for other station client or work from home clients. If ISP-A is down and ISP-B is running(which is not connected to C-name), other station clients or work from home clients unable to open to subdomain or run program, Hence we need to change the CNAME to ISP-B to run locally and other stations.

We have ubuntu server. Can somebody share a solution or an idea to this issue or do need to hire someone to sort?